# Clicking a link when enter key is pressed using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-instantsearch

I have been searching SO for a while so this should not be a duplicate. But, I am trying to trigger a link click when the enter key is pressed.

This is what I am working with:

```
handleKeyPress(target) {
  if(target.charCode==13){
    alert('Enter clicked!!!');    
  }
}
```

Search input:

```
<SearchBox
  type="text"
  value={value}
  onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
  className="search-box"
  placeholder="Search"
  aria-label="search"
  aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
  onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
/>
<div>
  <Link to={`/search?q=${value}`} className="btn submit-button"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></Link>
</div>
```

Using React Instant Search I want to submit the inputs 'value' when enter is clicked. Currently I can only submit the value when I physically click on:

```
<div>
  <Link to={`/search?q=${value}`} className="btn submit-button"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></Link>
</div>
```

I can get the link to fire. But, how can I get the same functionality as the link click when I press enter too? Any suggestions on how to link to the search value via KeyPress?

Comment: did you 'bind' handleKeyPress in your constructor?

Comment: I'm new to react.. Do you mean something like this `this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);` in my constructor props?

Comment: Are you using React Router?

Comment: @brooksrelyt yes ^. Alternatively, if you don't want to "bind" you could write handleKeyPress as an arrow function: handleKeyPress = (target) => {...etc...}

Comment: I am using react-static

Comment: A nicer way to handle the onKeyPress would be the wrap your <SearchBox> in a normal <form> element. The onSubmit prop is by default triggered by <enter> within the form area, thus you dont have to check for keycode

Comment: Where is your Link component imported from? Is it from react-static?

Comment: `import { Link, Router, RouteData } from 'react-static'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [react-statics documentation](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static/blob/master/docs/concepts.md#dynamic-routing) they recommend [installing Reach Router](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static/blob/master/docs/guides/dynamic-routes-reach-router.md) for dynamic routing. To [navigate programmatically with Reach Router](https://reach.tech/router) you should be able to import `navigate`.

```
import { navigate } from "@reach/router"
```

...

```
handleKeyPress(target) {
  // I'm guessing you have value stored in state
  const { value } = this.state;
  if(target.charCode==13){
    navigate(`/search?q=${value}`);
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

Honestly that seems like a lot of work when you could *probably* just do it with javascript.

```
handleKeyPress(target) {
  // I'm guessing you have value stored in state
  const { value } = this.state;
  if(target.charCode==13){
    const { href } = window.location;
    window.location.href = `${href}/search?q=${value}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 worked for me. I changed `${href}/search?q=${value}` to `/search?q=${value}`

Answer (score 3):

If you already `react-router-dom` you can use the following:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
class *ClassName* extends React.Component {
  ..
  handleKeyPress(target, value) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    if(target.charCode==13){
      history.push(`/search?q=${value}`);
    }
  }
  ..
  render() {
    return (
      ..
      <SearchBox
        value={value}
        ..
        onKeyPress={e => this.handleKeyPress(e, value)}
      />
    )
  }
  ..
}

export default withRouter(*ClassName*);
```

Important here ist that you use the `withRouter(..)` export to get the `history` from your props.